# Struts2 xml validation on HTML tags

Tags: html, validation, struts2

We are currently migrating our application from struts1 to struts2.

Our forms are composed with HTML tags and we are not using struts2 tags.
The forms are displayed without any problem.
But when we add the struts xml validation files the forms are empty (no input is displayed).

Is there a way to use the struts2 xml validation on HTML tags ?

Comment: Have you read the [docs](https://struts.apache.org/docs/validation.html)? Otherwise please be more precise and read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I've already read it.
I updated my post. As you can see the tags used (input, select..) are working because they are displayed and we can get their values from within actions.
but when we try to add xml validation files as specified in this documentation they disappear.

Comment: @kkung xml validation works regardless of form tags you use.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use the `validate()` method from the `ActionSupport` class. With this method you have a wide range of validation possibilities. With struts validators you only have the possibility to check single values without any relation, see [Struts form validation](https://struts.apache.org/docs/form-validation.html).

With that method you can check whatever you want:

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport {
    String valueToCheck = "";

    @Override
    public void validate() {
       if (valueToCheck.isEmpty()) {
          addFieldError("valueToCheck", "Please fill in...");
       }
    }
}
```

If the `fieldErrors`-Map is filled, the validation Method will return a result of type `input`, otherwise the `execute()`-Method will be called (or maybe something you defined).